# flutter wont update widgets to material design 3

Tags: flutter, material-design-3

My flutter app wont use materal desing 3 after adding useMaterial3:true in theme

I added the flag according to the the [blog](https://blog.codemagic.io/migrating-a-flutter-app-to-material-3/) and [material design website(flutter)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/useMaterial3.html)

Comment: Can you share your `MaterialApp`?

Answer (score 0):

try this code it should work fine .
`

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
        home: const HomePage(),
      );
    }
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, try it..

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: true),
              body: MyHomePage(),
            );
          }
        }
```